# lubridate:floor_date set reference start timestamp

Tags: r, timestamp, lubridate

I'm trying to floor continuous timestamps to '*every x hours*' with `lubridate:floor_date`. However, when my time interval is greater than the hour of the first timestamp, it floors relative to midnight instead of my first timestamp. I have not found a way to set a reference timestamp for my start time. I have timestamps in UTC but need to floor them relative to for example 6:00 and 18:00 local time, which would be 12 hour intervals when referenced to local midnight, but doesn't work for UTC time when it keeps referencing to (UTC) midnight.

I know I could convert my timestamps to local time, but that is less than ideal. Is there a way to define the reference timestamps for `floor_date` that I'm missing?

Basically, what I'd like to do is floor the timestamps "every hour" relative to the start of my timeseries instead of each timestamp individually flooring relative to its midnight.

```
timestamps<-structure(c(1578628800, 1578632400, 1578636000, 1578639600, 1578643200, 
1578646800, 1578650400, 1578654000, 1578657600, 1578661200), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")

floor_date(timestamps, '4 hours')

 [1] "2020-01-10 04:00:00 UTC" "2020-01-10 04:00:00 UTC" "2020-01-10 04:00:00 UTC"
 [4] "2020-01-10 04:00:00 UTC" "2020-01-10 08:00:00 UTC" "2020-01-10 08:00:00 UTC"
 [7] "2020-01-10 08:00:00 UTC" "2020-01-10 08:00:00 UTC" "2020-01-10 12:00:00 UTC"
[10] "2020-01-10 12:00:00 UTC"

floor_date(timestamps, '5 hours')

 [1] "2020-01-10 00:00:00 UTC" "2020-01-10 05:00:00 UTC" "2020-01-10 05:00:00 UTC"
 [4] "2020-01-10 05:00:00 UTC" "2020-01-10 05:00:00 UTC" "2020-01-10 05:00:00 UTC"
 [7] "2020-01-10 10:00:00 UTC" "2020-01-10 10:00:00 UTC" "2020-01-10 10:00:00 UTC"
[10] "2020-01-10 10:00:00 UTC"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `clock` package:

```
clock::date_floor(timestamps, 'hour', n = 4)
 [1] "2020-01-10 04:00:00 UTC" "2020-01-10 04:00:00 UTC"
 [3] "2020-01-10 04:00:00 UTC" "2020-01-10 04:00:00 UTC"
 [5] "2020-01-10 08:00:00 UTC" "2020-01-10 08:00:00 UTC"
 [7] "2020-01-10 08:00:00 UTC" "2020-01-10 08:00:00 UTC"
 [9] "2020-01-10 12:00:00 UTC" "2020-01-10 12:00:00 UTC"

clock::date_floor(timestamps, 'hour', n = 5)
 [1] "2020-01-10 01:00:00 UTC" "2020-01-10 01:00:00 UTC"
 [3] "2020-01-10 06:00:00 UTC" "2020-01-10 06:00:00 UTC"
 [5] "2020-01-10 06:00:00 UTC" "2020-01-10 06:00:00 UTC"
 [7] "2020-01-10 06:00:00 UTC" "2020-01-10 11:00:00 UTC"
 [9] "2020-01-10 11:00:00 UTC" "2020-01-10 11:00:00 UTC"
```